# How to select classes after detection on Detectron2

Tags: python

im creating a code that can use the detection from detectron2 (" faster_rcnn_R_50_DC5_3x"), but i just want him to select the class "person". How can i make a filter after the detection just to choose the classes i want and ignore the other on printing

[image]

for example, on that image it detected the ball and the car, and i just want to print the "person" detections

Comment: your question lacks research effort from your side, show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Set some conditions with the properties of the classes you want to add, and if they don't match the conditions, they won't be added